# Simple view for Video component

Tags: apache-flex, video, stream, red5, custom-component

I have to use the flash.media.Video component to play remote video files because I have a custom authentication mechanism (CRAM-MD5) in Red5 that doesn't allow to use VideoPlayer. I was trying to use OpenVideoPlayer but it fails on the server side (Error executing call: Service: null Method: play Num Params: 3 0: test/avatar.flv 1: NaN 2: NaN).

I just need to have the controllers on the top of the Video component: play, pause, stop, rewind, progress bar. Please can somebody recommend me a simple view for this? Or any solution would be ok!

**update:**
A sample code, the togglePause doesn't work properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="640" minHeight="480"
           initialize="init();">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.globalization.Collator;

        import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        private var nc:NetConnection;
        private var ns:NetStream;
        private var video:Video;
        private var meta:Object;
        private var videoURL:String = "test/avatar.flv";

        private function init():void {

            var params:Object = {
                user: "user",
                video_id: 2
            };

            nc = new NetConnection();
            nc.connect("rtmp://localhost/myapp", params);
            nc.client = this;
            nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,onConnectionStatus);
            nc.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR,onErrorHandler);
            nc.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityError);
        }

        private function onConnectionStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void {

            var nsClient:Object = {};
            nsClient.onMetaData = ns_onMetaData;
            nsClient.onCuePoint = ns_onCuePoint;

            ns = new NetStream(nc);
            ns.play(videoURL);
            ns.client = nsClient;

            video = new Video();
            video.attachNetStream(ns);
            uic.addChild(video);
        }

        private function onErrorHandler(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void{
        }

        private function onSecurityError(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void{
        }

        private function ns_onMetaData(item:Object):void {
        }

        private function ns_onCuePoint(item:Object):void {
        }

        public function onBWDone():void {
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:SpriteVisualElement id="uic" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="240" /> 
<mx:ControlBar x="10" y="330">
    <mx:Button label="Play/Pause" click="ns.togglePause();" />
    <mx:Button label="Rewind" click="ns.seek(0); ns.pause();" />
</mx:ControlBar>
```

Comment: I was trying to make it myself but there were problems with togglePause() - freezes - and I didn't even start to make the progressbar part of it... :S

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using NetStream class that, along with NetConnection, is responsible for retrieving media from Red5.

Check the documentation for NetStream: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html

There should be enough methods and events to build the required controls (like play(), pause() etc)

Also, consider looking into Open Source Media Framework. It provides great abstraction for building media players and allow to create plugins for additional functionality (Red5 authentication mechanism for example).

Besides, VideoPlayer component is OSMF based, so you can develop a custom plugin to communicate with your Red5 server and use it with Flex's VideoPlayer.

Comment: As I mentioned I tried to make the controls myself but at the very beginning I met an error: play/pause is not as easy as it looks like. Pause()-resume() doens't work, togglePause() pauses but goes back 1-2 secs then if I call it again it countinues for a couple of secs and it freezes. I hope you understand I don't want to go deeper and wasting time with a custom seeker and etc..

Comment: Then can you share at least some of your code how you use flash.media.Video?